# CRT Computer Monitor Keeps "Flickering" When Pi (With RetroPie) Plugged In

Tags: screen, retropie

I have this very annoying problem that I have no clue how to fix. So I've been trying to fix an arcade cabinet that my father started working on almost a decade ago as a part of his Christmas present, and I've gotten pretty far along now. I bought a 2GB Pi 4 and got everything working and running smoothly up until I plugged it into the CRT in the cabinet (I had actually been using my drawing tablet to set it up until this point, and everything had gone surprisingly well up until that point). For some reason, the video feed cuts out every 2 seconds or so and the monitor throws the "no signal" message (it basically keeps flickering on and off). Now, I've been doing a lot of digging around online and testing of my own, and I haven't made any headway, so I thought it'd be best to come here with my help. Here's what I've done and what I've learned so far.

I have a micro USB converter plugged into a powered VGA converter plugged into the monitor (which is a ViewSonic G90FB computer monitor btw), so I initially thought all of the converter cables were the problem. To be sure though, I plugged my setup into an old LCD monitor and it displays retropie just fine.

Here's some of the information from the back of the monitor that I thought was important to highlight (More can be found here: https://www.viewsonic.com/eu/products/archive/G90FB.php) :

- Name: ViewSonic G90fb
- Model No. VCDTS23283-2M
- AC 100 - 240 V ~
- 47-63Hz 2.0A

I figure that since the converters seemingly weren't the issue, that it could be the monitors fault, so I once again decided to test and see if that were the case. I plugged an older laptop with a VGA port in, and it displayed on the CRT just fine, so I know that the monitor isn't broken.

I then turned online and saw a bunch of people with a similar problem being recommended to edit the config.txt file, so I followed each bit of advice that other people found success with and still nothing worked.

I then decided to search the RPIconfig page (https://elinux.org/RPiconfig#Video), and found the "/opt/vc/bin/tvservice" commands, which I used to get these   results:

```
pi@retropie:~ $ /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -m CEA
Group CEA has 0 modes:
pi@retropie:~ $ /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -m DMT
Group DMT has 10 modes:
          mode 4: 640x480 @ 60Hz 4:3 clock:25MHz progressive
 (prefer) mode 16: 1024x768 @ 60Hz 4:3 clock:65MHz progressive
          mode 28: 1280x800 @ 60Hz 16:10 clock:83MHz progressive
          mode 32: 1280x960 @ 60Hz 4:3 clock:108MHz progressive
          mode 35: 1280x1024 @ 60Hz 5:4 clock:108MHz progressive
          mode 37: 1280x1024 @ 85Hz 5:4 clock:157MHz progressive
          mode 39: 1360x768 @ 60Hz 16:9 clock:85MHz progressive
          mode 47: 1440x900 @ 60Hz 16:10 clock:106MHz progressive
          mode 48: 1440x900 @ 75Hz 16:10 clock:136MHz progressive
          mode 85: 1280x720 @ 60Hz 16:9 clock:74MHz progressive
pi@retropie:~ $ /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -s
state 0x6 [DVI CUSTOM RGB full 4:3], 640x480 @ 60.00Hz, progressive
```

While set to "hdmi_group=2", I tried setting "hdmi_mode" to 4 and 16, which were the only modes the monitor would support (the others wouldn't display anything, so I gave up on testing them all).

Currently, I have it set at "hdmi_group=2" and "hdmi_mode=16" with no other changes made to the config script. I have no idea what the problem could be or if I'm even going in the right direction when trying to fix it. I can't just swap the monitor; it'd be a pain to refit everything, and the CRT makes it all feel more "retro", which my dad really wants. The only potential solution I can think of would be to by a micro hdmi to vga cable, but I don't want to make another purchase only for it to not fix the problem. It seems like many people have overcome this by editing the config.txt file, so it'd be great if I could do the same.

Comment: Try this - `hdmi_mode=87` (allows manual timings settings) and `hdmi_timings=1920 1 128 208 344 1440 0 1 3 56 0 0 0 60 0 234000000 1` - that's timings for 1920x1440 (which is apparently that monitors "native" resolution) at 60Hz

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead copy the text direct into the question: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/5014688).

Comment: I replaced the pictures with text, and tried the suggested settings, so now it's set at
```hdmi_group=2```
```hdmi_mode=87```
```hdmi_timings=1920 1 128 208 344 1440 0 1 3 56 0 0 0 60 0 234000000 1```
And still nothings seems to have changed. Is there a setting that I'm maybe missing? The only uncommented lines I have are ```dtparam=audio=on```, ```[pi4]```, 
```dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d```, and ```max_framebuffers=2```.